# How to use Hyperledger Fabric node SDK packages in an IBM Cloud Functions action?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an IBM Cloud Functions blockchain node.js action that uses a Hyperledger Fabric node SDK package, but I'm having trouble requiring the fabric-network package in the action.

Since it is a 3rd party package, it seems I need to upload the action as a zipped file, but when I do that, I see:

```
"error": "Initialization has failed due to: Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system\nExpected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc\nFound: [node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown]\nThis problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system"
```

I want to create a javascript action like the following:

```
'use strict'

const { X509WalletMixin, Gateway } = require('fabric-network')

async function main(params) {
  return { message: 'success' }
}
```

What is the correct way to handle 3rd party packages like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js modules with native dependencies need to be compiled for the same platform architecture as the serverless runtime. If you are bundling the `node_modules` directory from your local development machine, it probably won't match.

There are two approaches to use libraries with native dependencies...

1. Run `npm install` inside a Docker container from the platform images.
2. Building custom runtime image with libraries pre-installed.

**The first approach is easiest but can only be used when a zip file containing all source files and libraries is less than the action size limit (48MB).**

#### Running `npm install` inside runtime container

- Run the following command to bind the local directory into the runtime container and run `npm install`.

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/nodejsAction openwhisk/action-nodejs-v10 "npm install"
```

This will leave a `node_modules` folder with native dependencies compiled for correct runtime.

- Zip up the action source files including `node_modules` directory.

```
zip -r action.zip *
```

- Create new action with action archive.

```
ibmcloud wsk action create my-action --kind nodejs:10 action.zip
```

#### Building custom runtime image

- Create a `Dockerfile` with the `npm install` command run during build.

```
FROM openwhisk/action-nodejs-v10

RUN npm install fabric-network
```

- Build and push the image to Docker Hub.

```
$ docker build -t <USERNAME>/custom-runtime .
$ docker push <USERNAME>/custom-runtime
```

- Create new action using custom runtime image.

```
ibmcloud wsk action create my-action --docker <USERNAME>/custom-runtime action.zip
```

**Make sure the `node_modules` included in the `action.zip` does not include the same libraries files.**

Comment: I would recommend to not include any node_modules in action.zip when doing a custom runtime image, just use package.json and install all npm packages inside the image, the image gets cached then action.zip only your your files with no dependencies